# Stop refresh when Pop up opens

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In my asp.net application, page is refreshing specific time using `Response.AddHeader("Refresh","30")`, but if i open pop up(window.open) case also Page is refreshing then pop up closing. How to stop the refresh in parent page when Popup opens.

I tried with another code.Added below code in window,onload event.

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload()},30000)
```

How to increase refresh time when we open popup(window.open).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following code at the bottom of the page is what you need.

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload()},30000)
```

Comment: Hi Rajdeep, when i open the pop up refresh should be stop. after close the pop up again continue refresh in 30 seconds.